# Login with twitter always return error

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

I am try to add login with twitter but some how I am not able to get response. Everytime I got the error message (**error obtaining user auth token**). I know there are lot's SO post which has this issue but I am not able to login. I also try [advance setting](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation) but I got session nil. I also regenerate the consumer key and Secret but no luck. using swift 3.0

Here is my code

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self) { (session, error) in
     if (session != nil) {
     print("signed in as \(session?.userName ?? "")");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")");
            }
     }
```

> info.plist

[image]

> Appdelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        _ = DBSingleton.sharedInstance
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:TwitterKey.consumerKey, consumerSecret:TwitterKey.consumerSecret)
}
```

[image: attached log screenshot]

**Update:**
if we have application then it works fine but if not then it return errors.

Comment: Follow Twitter kit installation guide. https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation, Another way is to integrate twitter using fabric

Comment: @MuhammadUsman before long time fabric deprecated the twitter support.

Comment: Yeah my bad, Just checked again. Anyhow I usually integrate twitter using twitter-kit-ios official documentation

Comment: @MuhammadUsman yes i also do but they did not provide all the step and at one stage you stuck like me

Comment: please at least provide the reason for downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of R&D I got the success. Twitter has made call back url compulsory. I found from this [link](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/issues/74)

You need to add twitterkit-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (twitterkit-consumer key) in call back url at twitter dashboard setting.

I used this method for opening safari (make sure you add safari framework)

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self) { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session?.userName ?? "")");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")");
            }
        }
```